# Django reserve foreign key in views

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have a reverse query in a template that working on two tables connected together with Foreign Key.  That query is giving result what I want for now but in the future, it is clear will cause me serious problems about query optimization. I am sending the query to the database for all pictures related with the table that I am working with than I am showing only one of them.

I cannot adapt to the view function the reverse query that I wrote in HTML template.

### Here are my working codes:

in **models.py**

```
class EtkinlikModel(models.Model):
    ...

class FotografModel(models.Model):
    etkinlik = models.ForeignKey(EtkinlikModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in **views.py**

```
def EtkinlikView(request):
 etkinlikler = EtkinlikModel.objects.all().order_by("-olusturulma_tarihi")[:4]
    template = “…”
    context = {
        "pageName": title,
        "etkinlikler" : etkinlikler
    }
    return render(request,template,context)
```

in **template.html**

```
{% for etkinlik in etkinlikler  %}
    {{ etkinlik.etkinlik_adi }}

    {% for foto in etkinlik.fotografmodel_set.all|slice:":1"  %}
        {{ foto.foto }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

### codes for decreasing query loads

**views.py**

```
def EtkinlikView(request):
    etkinlikler = EtkinlikModel.objects.all().order_by("-olusturulma_tarihi")[:4]
    for etkinlik in etkinlikler:
        foto = etkinlik.fotografmodel_set.all()
    template = “…”
    context = {
        "pageName": title,
        "etkinlikler" : etkinlikler,
        "foto":foto
    }
    return render(request,template,context)
```

in **template.html**

```
{% for etkinlik in etkinlikler  %}
    {{ etkinlik.etkinlik_adi }} {{ etkinlik.id }}
       {% for f in foto  %}
            {{f.foto}}
       {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result of only one foto is shown repeatedly in every etkinlik object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def EtkinlikView(request):
    etkinlikler = EtkinlikModel.objects.all().order_by("-olusturulma_tarihi")[:4]
    template = "…"
    context = {
        "pageName": title,
        "etkinlikler" : etkinlikler,
    }
    return render(request,template,context)
```

in template

```
{% for etkinlik in etkinlikler  %}
{{ etkinlik.etkinlik_adi }} {{ etkinlik.id }}
   {{ etkinlik.fotografmodel_set.first.foto }}
{% endfor %}
```

hope this will work

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot.  I am wondering how does it work? Optimizing SQL query is my first priority of this issue. I assume it sends the request to the database for an only first _foto_ item related to _etkinlik_ object or it sends the request for all of the _foto_ items related to _etkinlik_, after the database responses it shows only first _foto_ of the item.?

Answer (score 2):

in template:

```
{% for etkinlik in etkinlikler  %}
{{ etkinlik.etkinlik_adi }} {{ etkinlik.id }}
   {{ etkinlik.fotografmodel_set.first.foto }}
{% endfor %}
```